How to match data from 2 tables of different sizes based on multiple criteria and extract the corresponding value in Google Sheets
I have a table which contains data about the Top Speed of the cars:

I have another table with Available Cars, where I would like to add the Top Speed from the First table. The expected result should look like this:

I tried to use vlookup for this situation but the result is not what I expected.
Formula that I used:
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(A3:A&B3:B, {E3:E&F3:F, A3:C}, 4,0))

The first problem that I can see is that the Car Model names from the second table are in someway different from the first table. I was thinking that I can solve this using wildcars, so I can get a partial match, but again, the result is not as expected. Also, the tables are of different sizes. Another thing to consider is that both tables will be updated in the future with additional entries, so the formula should work without updating the range.
Formula with wildcard:
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(A3:A&"*"&B3:B&"*", {E3:E&F3:F, A3:C}, 4,0))


You can check the sample data here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18OZweTUPVLQQNQQEI_1YN-suHIXMiyiExgwSdC1c9mM


You may try:
=map(E3:E,F3:F,lambda(e,f,if(or(e="",f=""),,ifna(+filter(C:C,A:A=e,regexmatch(f,"(?i)"&B:B)),"NF"))))



You are a beast! The solution works and I have not found any more situations for which adjustments need to be made. Thank you!
